# Pandas - joining rows with same value, write to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I made a dataframe in Pandas that looks like this:

```
 disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
0                ATL            5          2
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
1                ATL           10          2
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
2                ATL           15          4
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
3                ATL           20          1
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
4                ATL           25          1
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
5                ATL           30          3
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
6                ATL           40          2
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
7                ATL           45          3
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
8                ATL           50          1
  disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
9                ATL           55          3
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
10                ATL           60          3
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
11                ATL           65          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
12                ATL           70          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
13                ATL           75          2
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
14                ATL           85          3
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
15                ATL           90          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
16                ATL           95          2
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
17                ATL          110          2
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
18                ATL          115          2
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
19                ATL          120          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
20                ATL          197          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
21                ATL          278          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
22                BKN            5          2
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
23                BKN           10          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
24                BKN           15          4
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
25                BKN           20          2
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
26                BKN           25          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
27                BKN           30          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
28                BKN           40          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
29                BKN           45          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
30                BKN           50          2
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
31                BKN           55          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
32                BKN           60          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
33                BKN           70          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
34                BKN           75          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
35                BKN           80          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
36                BKN           85          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
37                BKN           90          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
38                BKN           95          1
   disadvantaged_team seconds_left num_ic_inc
```

Now I would like to write the results to a csv file, depending on the team, e.g. all of the rows containing ATL should be in one file, the ones with BKN in another. I've already written each row to a separate file using iterrows() but as I said I want all rows of a team in one csv.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for value in df['disadvantaged_team'].unique(): 
    df[df['disadvantaged_team'] == value].to_csv(value + '.csv')
```

Not checked, but the logic holds:

1) Get a list of all unique values in the series

2) Use value to filter the main df

3) Write the results to CSV

Comment: Thanks @billett ! I tried it but now I get `TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable`

Comment: the .unique was the problem. It did what I wanted when I removed it. Thanks @billett! :)

Comment: Sorry! Needed to call `.unique` as a function. Will update now.

Answer (score 0):

one quick solution could be group by :

`for g,f in df.groupby("disadvantaged_team"):
        f.to_csv(g+'.csv')`

or in another way :

```
df.groupby("disadvantaged_team").apply(lambda f : f.to_csv(x["disadvantaged_team"].max()+'.csv'))
```